# JQuery Mobile, How to force orientation change, Programmatically

Tags: jquery-mobile

Throw JQuery Mobile is there are any way to show the Page in Landscape by code,
I don't want to use orientationchange but I want to fire it Programmatically!

Any help,

Comment: It's not possible by JQM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, You can't do it

**But**, Try to add some layer over when user using mobile & portrait by using **CSS**

Something like...

**HTML :**

```
<div class="locked"></div>
```

**CSS :**

```
@media only screen
        and (min-device-width: 320px)
        and (max-device-width: 480px)
        and (orientation: portrait) 
{

    .locked {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position:fixed;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        z-index:9999;
    }

}
```

So style this layer whatever you want, example some arrow or fake your website screenshot or fake css transform rotate, Just for let users change orientation :P

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/cpJgT/show/ Try on your mobile

Comment: but where to add @media only screen ?

Comment: your CSS @BasharAbuShamaa